# Copying files across a network with Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, filepath, shutil

I am trying to loop through a list of filepaths for files I have throughout the entire network at my company. The filepaths have locations of various drives throughout the network.

The user submitted the file once upon a time and the filepath was passed through at the point of submission. However, the file drive is not the same for every user and is not the same for what that drive is named on my machine.

For example: a path like **X:\Users\Submissions\Bob's File.xlsx** may coincide with the same drive and file but named differently on my machine:
**K:\Users\Submissions\Bob's File.xlsx**

Each user has the potential of using a different letter for that particular drive for a various number of reasons.

Is there a way I can make my pattern string that I pass in smart enough to be able to find the proper directory and locate that file? Any ideas would be great.

Thank you

```
import pandas as pd
import shutil as sh

copydir = r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\PythonSpyderDesktop\Extractor\Models"

file_path_list = r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\PythonSpyderDesktop\Extractor\FilePathList.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(file_path_list)

i = 1 #Start at 2nd row
for i in range(1, len(data)):
    try:
        sh.copyfile(data.FilePath[i], copydir)
        print("Copied over file: " + data.FilePath[i])
    except:
        print ("File not found.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear. It revolves around the source & dest arguments being passed to copyfile:

```
    sh.copyfile(data.FilePath[i], copydir)
```

It's hard to tell what pathnames you're extracting from the .CSV, but apparently source files may have the "wrong" drive letter, and/or the destination directory `copydir` may have the "wrong" drive letter. The script apparently runs on multiple machines, and those machines have diverse drive letters mounted.

Write a helper function that finds the "right" drive letter. It should accept a pathname like `copydir`, then probe a search list, then return a corrected pathname.

Given a list of drive letters, you can iterate through them and test whether a pathname exists using [`os.path.exists()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists). Return the first one found.

Use [`splitdrive()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitdrive) to parse out components of the input pathname.

Suppose that both source and dest may need their drive letters fixed up. Then the call might look like this:

```
    sh.copyfile(fix_path(data.FilePath[i]), fix_path(copydir))
```